# Why can't I use a variable for 'typeof' in Quartz.NET?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm trying to create a job in an ASP.NET (C#) form using Quartz.NET, and here's what I have so far:

```
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(count + "_job", schedID, typeof(HTTPtoFTP));
```

Problem is, I don't want to link *directly* to the HTTPtoFTP class, because depending on what the user picks on the form , it'll link to a seperate class. I've tried using a variable in place of HTTPtoFTP, but I get the error:

> The type or namespace 'mergedJobType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why is this? I guess one way to do this is an IF statement where I just copy the line and change the typeof for each possibility, but it seems like I'd have to replicate all the other lines that refer to jobDetail too.

Comment: I think you'd have to provide more code, considering the identifier the error mentions isn't seen in what you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, I think what you are looking for is `mergedJobType.GetType()` That returns the type object of an object's class.

Comment: Thanks all, now I get 'Job class must implement the Job interface.' :(  Type mergedJobType2 = mergedJobType.GetType();

            JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(count + "_job", schedID, mergedJobType2);

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, there are two most common ways to retrieve a type.

**When the type is known at compile-time**, use `typeof`.
**When the type is only known at runtime and you have a reference to object of that type**, call its `GetType()` to get the Type object.

Note that for generic types there's a difference between, say, `typeof(List<int>)` and `typeof(List<>)` so if you're into heavy reflection use, you may want to learn how to deal with generic runtime types.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's precisely what `typeof` does, it takes the label for a type and returns the relevant `Type` object.

What you would want would be `mergedJobType.GetType()`. `GetType()` returns the type of an instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of a variable, by using `mergedJobType.GetType()`.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's comments so far are correct.  I just went through this myself.  The following line should do what you need as long as mergedJobType is an instance of a class that implements IJob:

```
 JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(count + "_job", schedID, mergedJobType.GetType());
```

The error you're getting "Job class must implement the Job interface.' :( `Type mergedJobType2 = mergedJobType.GetType(); JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail(count + "_job", schedID, mergedJobType2);` is more than likely due to mergedJobType not implementing the IJob interface.  All Quartz.Net jobs must implement the IJob interface.